# Create a drop down menu and get items from database, whats wrong with my code I alway get empty spaces

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a drop down menu to get items from database.
Following is my code:

```
<select name="select" class="ed" id="partname">
<option id="0">--Select Part Name/Description--</option>
<?php 

 include('connect.php');    

 $getallparts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parts");
 while($viewallparts = mysql_fetch_array($getallparts)){
 ?>

<option id="<?php echo $viewallparts['parts_id']; ?>"><?php echo$getallparts['part_description'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>

</select>
```

What's wrong with my code? I always get empty spaces..

Comment: is a space missing after `echo` in your code inside `<option>` tag?

Comment: $getallparts['part_description'] why are you retreiving from getallparts try from $viewallparts['part_description']...

Answer (score 0):

As Michael Radionov said there should be a space after echo 
kindly use

```
<option id="<?php echo $viewallparts['parts_id']; ?>">
<?php echo    $getallparts['part_description'] ?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="select" class="ed" id="partname">
<option id="0">--Select Part Name/Description--</option>
<?php 

 include('connect.php');    

$getallparts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM parts");
 while($viewallparts = mysql_fetch_array($getallparts)){
 ?>
<option id="<?php echo $viewallparts['parts_id']; ?>">
<?php echo $getallparts['part_description'] ?>
</option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in echo statement because logic is correct.
your declaration part took error due to missing of semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find mysqli_query takes 2 parameters, parameter 1 is mysqli_connect and the second one is the query.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("**" , "**" , "**" , "**");
$q = mysqli_query($con , $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<?php echo$getallparts['part_description'] ?>`

with `<?php echo $viewallparts['part_description'] ?>`.

Code was wrong (`space` after echo was missing) and you were echoing from the wrong variable `$getallparts`.